# Mathematical proof for the following infinite double summation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, physics, mathematical-physics

In this [Physics Stack Exchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783356/is-this-a-proof-of-a-mathematical-statement-using-physics), I detailed my discovery of the following equation
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(2i+1)(2j+1)\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi}{2}\right)} = \frac{\pi^2}{48},$$

through solving a physics problem in two different ways.

Question: I was wondering if there exists any other proof of this equation, that is more 'mathematical'?

Here, I mean 'mathematical', in the sense that it does not delve into the physical context of a specific problem as done in the post, but rather relies on theorems of pure mathematics to prove the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$After a few days, I was able to construct a proof of this via the help of the [Mittag-Leffer Expansion](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Hyperbolic_Secant_Function)  of $\sech(\pi z)$ which shows that:

$$\sech (\pi z) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac {2 k + 1} { 4 z^2 + (2 k + 1)^2}$$

The double summation thus becomes,

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}\sech\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2}\pi}{2}\right)}{(2i+1)(2j+1)} &= \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}(2k+1)}{(2i+1)(2j+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]}\\
&= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}(2k+1)^2}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]} \\
\end{align*} $$

Notice that $i, j, k$ are interchangeable. Letting the sum be $S$, we get,

$$ \begin{align*}
S &= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}(2k+1)^2}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]}  \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}(2i+1)^2}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]} \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}(2j+1)^2}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]} \\
\end{align*}$$
Summing them,
$$
\begin{align*}
3S &= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}[(2i+1)^2 + (2j+1)^2 + (2k+1)^2]}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2+(2k+1)^2]} \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{i+j+k}}{(2i+1)(2j+1)(2k+1)} \\
\end{align*}$$

Again, since $i, j, k$ are interchangeable, we get,

$$ S = \frac{4}{3\pi}\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}\right)^3$$

Note that $\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}$ is the famous [Leibniz formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) which is exactly equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. We then get the final result:

$$ \begin{align*}
S &= \frac{4}{3\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^3 \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{48}\\
\end{align*}$$